# Is it possible to distribute apps without the Apple Developer Program?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to get the file from the Organizer in Xcode after you've archived it, and distribute it to multiple devices without the Apple Developer Program being paid?

I have an app for in-house use and would like to distribute it without having to pay 299 for the Enterprise program or 99 for the Apple Dev program.

Thanks

Comment: No, for that scenario you would need an enterprise development membership or you could use a $99 personal membership and distribute using the B2B VPP program.

Comment: Simplest answer : You cant. You can make use of TestFlight to destribute it to limited audience by adding them as internal and external testers, but that will be only for a limited time and not a scalable approach. Get developer certificate or enterprise certificate

Comment: Thank you. Is TestFlight free or does it require any fee? This is a project which will be closed in a years time I think and if I can use TestFlight, and users only have to install a new update every 30 days or whatever is required Im fine with that.

Comment: TestFlight is free.

Comment: Sasquatch but i still need apple developer program?

Comment: Correct. Technically TestFlight is free, but you still require a paid program membership in order to access it.

Comment: Thanks. Apple is not as smooth as working with as android. Thats for sure :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is no : **NO**

You wont be able to archive the project without paying for Apple's Developer account.

You might ask **Why?**

The Program membership was indeed required in order to sign the provisioning certificates required to deploy apps to devices.